# LQR with prediction - How?

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

I have heard that LQR controllers can not only have estimation, but prediction too.

Let's say that we have a discrete state space system:

$$ x(k+1) = Ax(k) + Bu(k) \\ y(k) = Cx(k) + Du(k) $$

If we count $k = 1, 2, 3, \dots , n$

Then our state space model will be:
$$ x(2) = Ax(1) + Bu(1) \\ y(1) = Cx(1) + Du(1) \\
x(3) = Ax(2) + Bu(2) \\ y(2) = Cx(2) + Du(2) \\
x(4) = Ax(3) + Bu(3) \\ y(3) = Cx(3) + Du(3) \\
\vdots \\
x(n+1) = Ax(n) + Bu(n) \\ y(n) = Cx(n) + Du(n) $$

If $$x(2) = Ax(1) + Bu(1) \\ y(1) = Cx(1) + Du(1)$$

Then we kan say that :

$$x(3) = A[Ax(1) + Bu(1)] + Bu(2) \\ y(2) = C[Ax(1) + Bu(1)] + Du(2) $$

And we simplify:

$$x(3) = A^2x(1) + ABu(1) + Bu(2) \\ y(2) = CAx(1) + CBu(1) + Du(2) $$

Then we add another one:
$$x(4) = Ax(3) + Bu(3) \\ y(3) = Cx(3) + Du(3) $$

Then we kan say that :

$$x(4) = A[A^2x(1) + ABu(1) + Bu(2)] + Bu(3) \\ y(3) = C[A^2x(1) + ABu(1) + Bu(2)] + Du(3) $$

We can simplify

$$x(4) = A^3x(1) + A^2Bu(1) + ABu(2) + Bu(3) \\ y(3) = CA^2x(1) + CABu(1) + CBu(2) + Du(3) $$

So my conclusion is: If I remember the inputs $u(k)$ for 10 samples. I can predict the future values of states $x(k+1)$? Is this the method for predict future states from a LQR controller? Or am I totaly wrong?

Comment: I believe the term prediction is more often in the context of discrete observers (such as a Kalman filter). But I believe the idea behind it is indeed the same. But keep in mind that you do need to know which future inputs will be applied in order to predict into the future state and output of the system. Also fun fact from this it can also be really easy to derive the controllability matrix (and with a few extra steps the observability matrix).

Comment: Ok. So to do a simple LQR controller who is allways predict some states in the future. I need to derive the controllability matrix and observability matrix?

Comment: No, I meant that these predictions steps can be used to explain why the controllability matrix looks the way it does and why it has to be full rank in order for a system be called "controllable".

Comment: Those matrecies can I see got the shaped form in the last two equations in my question.

Comment: But If I want prediction in my LQ controller. Does that requrie a memory of input signals?

Comment: LQR is a predictor for an infinitly horizon. MPC is a predictor which uses a finit horizon, but computes a new feedback for each iteration.

Comment: @WG but if I want to have an LQR who can handle time delay. Shouldn't I have a predictor which estimate future states?

Comment: You could also just extend the state space such that it includes those inputs and make a LQR controller that extended system. But if you want to incorporate this on a real physical system, then indeed you would need to store these inputs in memory yourself.

Comment: How about the Smith Predictor by Otto Smith. Running a parallell system of a system who has not a delay included. Give the state feedback of the difference of real states minus predicted states. Just like an IMC.

Comment: So a MPC require a memory for inputs ? Or can I just create an extended LQR who predict future states ?

Comment: Do I need to do a real time identification for applying prediction?